# Make the `navset_tab()` fillable in `page_navbar()` in shiny with `bslib`

Tags: css, r, bslib

The main thing I put in `Nav1` is a `navset_hidden()`, I utilize an `actionButton()` to display a modal where in-page navigation is done.

The above reason I do this is to utilize as much page space as possible. In actual application, the module I'm wrapping is primarily for drawing, with controls on the left and display on the right.

But I ran into an issue where `navset_hidden()` or `layout_sidebar()` doesn't fill the entire page height as it does in `Nav2`, but rather is based on the content.

My ultimate goal is to implement something similar to that button in the top left corner of github's dashboard, like opening a drawer from the left to navigate and be able to search, but my primary goal is to fix the problem of the `navset_hidden` or `layout_sidebar()` not filling the entire page.

```
library(shiny)
library(bslib)

nav1UI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  layout_sidebar(
    sidebar = sidebar(open = "always",
      paste0("sidebar of ", id)
    ),
    paste0("main of ", id),
    lapply(1:20, function(i) {
      h1(i)
    })
  )
}

ui <- page_navbar(
  title = "MyApp",
  nav_panel("Nav1", style = "position: relative;",
    actionButton("nav1_select", "select", style = "position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 1000;"),
    navset_hidden(id = "nav1_navset",
      nav_panel_hidden("A", nav1UI("A")),
      nav_panel_hidden("B", nav1UI("B")),
      nav_panel_hidden("C", nav1UI("C")),
      nav_panel_hidden("D", nav1UI("D"))
    )
  ),
  nav_panel("Nav2",
  layout_sidebar(
    sidebar = sidebar(
      "sidebar of Nav2"
    ),
    "main of Nav2"
  )
),
  nav_panel("Nav3", "content of Nav3")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$nav1_select, {
    showModal(modalDialog(
      title = "Select one",
      selectInput("nav_panel_to_go", NULL, choices = c("A", "B", "C", "D")),
      easyClose = TRUE,
      footer = tagList(
        modalButton("Close"),
        actionButton("go", "Go", class = "btn-success")
      )
    ))
  })

  observeEvent(input$go, {
    nav_select("nav1_navset", input$nav_panel_to_go)
    removeModal()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```